# How to restrict libraries used in an android library project so that the app which use my library cannot access the libraries inside it?

Tags: android, android-library

I have a library project uses some library files like universal image loader.
If an app uses my library(provided as aar), it can access the functions of universal image loader as well. How to restrict it so that user cannot use this?

Comment: What i want to achieve is: if developer wants to use a library he has to import it. He should not be able to access the library which i have included in my library project. This also helps if the developer wants to use a different version of the same library. Otherwise it will not allow different versions of jar to be present(one in my library project, one in their app)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The developer is free to use whatever libraries the developer wants to. If the developer wishes to use an image-loading library, and for whatever reason the developer chooses the discontinued Universal Image Loader, that is the developer's right.

If you find this to be unacceptable, only distribute your library to your subordinates, who you can order to not use that library.

Comment: I don't want to restrict it. What i want o achieve is: if developer wants to use a library he has to import it. He should not be able to access the library which i have included in my library project. This also helps if the developer wants to use a different version of the same library. Otherwise it will not allow different versions of jar to be present(one in my library project, one in their app).

Comment: @Mr.Rao: Your library should be pulling in UIL via its artifact in Maven Central or JCenter, then. The developer using your library, if needed, can adjust their `build.gradle` file (or the equivalent) to pull in a different version of UIL.